# Looping through Excel rows copying and pasting them in SEPARATE Power Point Slides

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, powerpoint

I'm trying to loop through 3 rows in Excel and copy them and paste them into three separate power point slides.

This code will copy ALL 3 rows and paste ALL 3 rows in three separate slides. HOWEVER, I'm trying to copy row 1 in slide 1, row 2 in slide 2 and row 3 in slide 3. Is there any way to do this?

```
Sub Copy_Paste_ExcelPPT()
Dim PPTApp As Powerpoint.Application
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngarray As Variant
Dim ExcRng As Range
'Create new instance of PowerPoint
Set PPTApp=New PowerPoint.Application
PPTApp. Visible=True 
'Create a new presentation
Set PPTPres=PPTApp.Presentations.Add
'Loop through each row in the excel file
Set rng =Range("F4:H6")
For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each row In row.Cells
        'Create an array that houses references to the ranges we want to export
        rngarray= Array(rng)
        'Loop through this array, copy the row, create a new slide and paste the row in a different slide 
        For x=LBound(rngarray) To UBound(rngarray)
            Set a reference to the range we want to export
            Set ExcRng=rngarray(x)
            'Copy the range
            ExcRng.Copy
            'Create a new slide in the presentation
            Set PPTSlide=PPTPres.Slides.Add(x+1,ppLayoutBlank)
            'Paste the range in the slide
            PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
        Next x
    Next cell
Next row
End Sub
```

This code will copy ALL 3 rows and paste ALL 3 rows in three separate slides. I'm trying to copy row 1 in slide 1, row 2 in slide 2 and row 3 in slide 3. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Copy each range e.g. 'Range("F4:F6").Copy', etc. and paste into a new slide?

Comment: @GMalc Thank you for your response! I'm looking into Copy each "row" so F4:H4, F5:H5 and F6:H6 into three separate slides. F4:H4 paste in Slide 1, F5:H5 paste in slide 2 and F6:H6 in slide 3. I'm looking into using a loop to do this, that way when I have 50+ rows I don't have to hard code each row as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested)

```
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Range("F4:H4") 'change "Name" to Sheet name
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Range("F5:H5")
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Range("F6:H6")

rngarray = Array(rng1, rng2, rng3)

For x=LBound(rngarray) To UBound(rngarray)
```

**EDIT** changed to meet OP requirements;
I've tested the below code and it will add a new pps, copy each range in each row until the last row, then paste into a new pps.slide, and loop. Note: I tried to keep as much of your code as possible.

```
Dim ppTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
ppTApp.Visible = True

Set ppTPres = ppTApp.Presentations.Add

Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to meet your needs
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 4 To lRow

    ws.Cells(x, 6).Resize(, 3).Copy

    Set ppTSlide = ppTPres.Slides.Add(ppTPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ppTSlide.Shapes.Paste

Next x
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm looking into Copy each "row" so F4:H4, F5:H5 and F6:H6 into three separate slides. F4:H4 paste in Slide 1, F5:H5 paste in slide 2 and F6:H6 in slide 3. I'm looking into using a loop to do this, that way when I have 50+ rows I don't have to hard code each row as shown in your answer.

Comment: Glad to help, sorry it took so long i had to understand what you needed.

Comment: No worries! Thank YOU for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Hi @GMalc I was wondering if you knew how to copy only rows B4,E4,L4,N4,P4, Q4. For some reasons I'm having trouble looping through those specific columns because they are not next to each other. I only seem to get the looping on continues columns like F4:H4.

Comment: Sorry, I was not available this weekend. Yes, If you are still pasting the cells into a pps. Then try: `ws.Range("B4,E4,L4,N4,P4:Q4").Copy`

Comment: so If I wanted to copy both ranges into the same slide I would just have to write "ws.Range("B4,E4,L4,N4,P4:Q4")".Copy                           under "ws.Cells(x, 6).Resize(, 3).Copy" ?

Comment: It will have to be outside of your `For loop` or else you will produce another X number of slides that will have `Range("B4,E4,L4,N4,P4:Q4")`, so you need to decide if you want that special set of data in the first slide or the last slide. You could place it before the `For loop` or after the `For loop`, you will need to place a copy of the `Set ppTSlide` line below this new line. Note: I have not tested.